# how to develop moodle webservices in php?

Tags: php, web-services, moodle

I know basics about webservices and I am thinking to develop webservice plugin functions (services) in moodle so any one could you tell me what steps should I follow please?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not watched you take a look here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client